# Symfony2 "@Type" in property Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profil::$actualites was never imported

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I am new to Symfony2 in general. This issue relates to  JMS Serializer annotations and FOSRestBundle though.

I have the following Profile.php Entity with an Actualite Field that i'm looking to set them as an Array through [Type Annotation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type).

```
class Profile  {
...

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Actualite", mappedBy="profil",cascade={"persist"}, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */


     /**
     * @Type("array<Actualite>")
     */
    private $actualites;
...
}
```

But i'm getting the following error :

```
"@Type" in property Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profil::$actualites was never imported.
```

To solve the problem i had add the following line but the problem still :

```
use Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Actualite;
```

Comment: Why did you correct the typo in your question but accepted the answer ?! Is it still not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you insert this "use" in your Profile entity ?

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
```

EDIT :

You have set your

```
@Type("array<Actualie>")
```

But I think it's

```
@Type("array<Actualite>")
```

Comment: +1 thank you i have forgotten to insert it :), excuse me but the field dosn't apear in the response :o !!

Comment: i have set Actualite field as array to get the field as an array in my json response

Comment: maybe a typo error ? see my edit

Comment: the same result .. the field isn't displayed

Comment: I think about a relationship with your entities

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52509/discussion-between-perroin-thibault-and-abdellah-selassi)